# Connect to a Database located inside a VM through Qt5

Tags: sql, database, qt

I am using a **Mac** and **Parallel Desktops**. In my *Win7* installation (in Parallel) I have **pgAdmin** and a simple test database and table.

What I am trying to do is use the example that comes with *Qt Creator* named **Qt SQL Browser** in order to connect to that Database.

Due to the fact that the db is inside Parallels I don't
 know how to connect though. What should I input in the configuration screen of **Qt SQL Browser** in order to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things need to happen to access that database.

1. The database needs to be accessible outside of localhost.
2. You need to have the correct plugin for database access built and in the right plugins folder (or in the relative path next to your exe).

### Database Accessible

The port that the database is running on (`5432` is the default for postgres), needs to be allowed through the firewall on that computer (the Win7 install).

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

And to make life easier, you should also make pinging the Windows 7 computer available through the firewall, too.

http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7

And you need to get the ip address that Parallels sees the other computer on.  (To find this, on the Windows 7 computer in the command prompt, type `ipconfig` and see what the network card's address is.  It is probably something like `192.168.1.X`.

If the computer is visible from your mac, you should get replies when you type:

```
ping 192.168.1.6
```

Assuming that 6 is the number your Parallels network driver picked.

So after all of the above is completed, the database location is probably going to be:

```
192.168.1.6
```

This is what you will want to put in your Qt SQL Browser configuration screen under `Hostname:`

And be sure that the port represents the port you are using on your setup (modify `Port:` to reflect this setting, e.g. `5432`).

### Get the Qt PostGres SQL Driver Working

Include the qt SQL module.

```
QT += sql
```

Get the plugin built and available for your build.

https://www.google.com/search?q=qt+build+postgresql+driver

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql

Basically, you find the example project or the plugin project for building it, and then you put it in a folder that your executable expects it to be found.  `qtmacdeploy` should help with this, if the plugin was built in the normal folder.

When the driver is in place properly, it should be listed when you run this command in your code:

```
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

It looks like in Qt 5, more of the drivers are built and included by default.  You can see in the top of `qsqlconnectiondialog.cpp` where it does `ui.comboDriver->addItems(drivers);`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#drivers

### Note about Security

Usually exposing a database to be directly accessible over a network isn't the best practice.  Depending on the kind of database it isn't sent securely and is open to attacks.

Usually programs accessing the database use a server side service, like a php backend that can access the database, and using a small set of commands.  The database is only directly accessible by the php scripts running on the server, and the php provides the public interface to the database, with as much security as you need. Then you can limit login attempts, only allow specific kinds of queries, so often, better user management, etc.  This is common for use with MySQL.

https://www.google.com/search?q=database+security+best+practices+postgres

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tested the proposed steps and indeed they solve the problem, also very good information on the subject in general.

Comment: Depending on your network configuration, it may be needed to allow clients IP or Subnets to connect to the DB. The postgres‘ pg_hba.conf file.